# Fixed point iteration algorithm when the inputs have dependencies

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

A usual fixed point problem has the form $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$, and you can efficiently solve it by finding the root to $f(x)-x$. What if I now have several dependent inputs $x_{k+1}=f(x_k, y_k)$, and $y_k=g(x_{k-1}, y_{k-1})$. I can certainly run many iterations until $f$ converges (assume a fixed point exists), but is there a more clever algorithm for this?

Comment: If you can find a root of $(x,y)\mapsto (x-f(x,y), y-g(x,y))$, say, by the Newton method, then yes. What's the difference?

Comment: @fedja, thanks for the comment. Actually this is right, but I guess my real question was whether there is a way to decouple this, especially when the input has very large dimensions. That should probably be a new post.